# Is there a method or a function to generate integers that are only divisible by 3?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, functions

Is there a method or a function to generate integers that are only divisible by 3?

Comment: If you mean by $3$ and no other prime, then $3^n$.

Comment: @RahulNarain $3*4=12$, $12 mod2 = 0$

Comment: What do you mean? If $n$ is an integer divisible by $3$, then we have another integer $n/3$ which also divides $n$. So I guess the only solution to your problem is the constant function $3$.

Comment: Wow...I just remembered the Fundamental Theorem of Arithmetic and realized how big of a brain fart that was.

Comment: I read "generate integers that are only divisible by 3" as "generate only integers that are divisible by 3", sorry.

Comment: No. If it divisible by $3$, it is also divisible by $-3$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Every integer is also divisible by $1$, so the collection is empty.

If you're OK with having $1$ as a divisor, every integer is also divisible by itself, so it's just $3$.

If you mean the set of integers for which $3$ is the only **prime** divisor then you may use the following algorithm:

```
 1. Let x = 3 and S be empty.
 2. Add x and -x to S.
 3. Multiply x by 3 and set x equal to that.
 4. Go to 2.
```

Answer (score 2):

There is no integer that is only divisible by $3$.  Every integer is always divisible by $1$.